# ¿Como llenar un dataDable con el valor de un textBox?

Tags: c#

Quiero pasar el valor de un textbox a un `dataTable`

```
valor.Text = dataTable...
```

No uso Base de Datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Se crea el dataTable
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//Creamos una columna para el datatable
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Columna1", typeof(String));

//agregamos la columna creada al dataTable
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

//ahora creamos una fila para el DataTable
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

//Aqui es donde asignamos el valor del textBox al valor del row a agregar al DT
dr[0] = textBox.Text;

//agregamos la fila al final del dataTable
dt.Rows.Add(dr);


// o lo insertas en cierta posicion
int yourPosition = 0;
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, yourPosition);
```